# dynamically related files in Dreamweaver cc

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm just coding a html page for webdevelopers. For convinience i use php includes. For example in index.php i have `<?php include('header.php'); ?>` which includes all css and js files.

Dreamweaver cc does undestand include of header.php and shows it in Related Files bar. But doesn't show included css' and js'. Even when i make a Discover dynamically-related files.

Is it possible to make a dreamweaver go through header.php and show all css and js files listed there? header.php has simple html code like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/container.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver's engine can't always reference includes called in an included file.  While there is nothing wrong with what you are doing from a syntax standpoint it just violates DW's internal rules on what it thinks includes are supposed to contain.  There's no way to force it to work other than breaking up the file into multiple includes...it's a limitation of DW programming.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a nice feature (or maybe it already even exists).
I got a similar problem as you, that's solvable:
Just upgraded to Dreamweaver CC, and now related files are not discovered any more from .html files, whereas it would include them in DW CS6.
In .php files there's nothing wrong: it just displays the related files in top of the window as in previous versions.

What am I doing wrong? I cannot really believe Adobe skipped this feature just for .html files.